# Dash non-interactive non-login rc file

Tags: shell, configuration, dash

Does dash have a non-interactive non-login rc file? I've read the man page, which recommends `.profile` for login shells and `$ENV` environment variable for interactive shells.

Is there anything that runs for non-interactive non-login shells, such as `zsh`'s `zshenv` files, or `bash`'s `$BASH_ENV` environment variable? Is there an equivalent file for Bourne shell too?

---

Best I can come up with so far (although not ideal at all as it requires me editing every single script) is to edit the shebang as follows:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh /path/to/script

f
```

where `/path/to/script` contains

```bsh
f() { echo "/path/to/script"; }
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical shell does not have an rc file that is read for non-interactive shells.

`.profile`is read for a login shell that is identified by an `argv[0]` that starts with a `-`.

`$ENV` is read by an interactive POSIX shell and if not set already, the shell uses it's own default. This is `.kshrc` for `ksh`, `.bashrc` for `bash` and `.shrc` for newer versions of the `Bourne Shell`.

Dash however does not define a default `$ENV` and thus typically does not read it, even when in interactive mode.

Comment: What a shame! :(